# Message Passing in Java with Channels, send, receive

Tags: java, channel, message-passing

I am using the JMP library (http://ants.inf.um.es/staff/jlaguna/jmp/javadoc/), and I want to know how can I create 2 threads that print a Char and wait for the other prints his (by sending him a msg).

The result should be something like this:

```
Main(){
ThreadB();
ThreadC();
}

Output:
B
C
B
C
...
```

And this is what I have done:

```
import messagepassing.Channel;

public class Main3 {

    static Channel canalBC = new Channel();
    static Channel canalCB = new Channel();


    public static void procesoB(final Channel canalBC, final Channel canalCB){
        Thread thCliente = new Thread(new Runnable () {
             @Override public void run (){
                for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                canalCB.receive();  
                System.out.println("B");
                canalBC.send(1);
                }
          }
         } , "A");
         thCliente.start();
    }
    public static void procesoC(final Channel canalBC, final Channel canalCB){
        Thread thCliente = new Thread(new Runnable () {
             @Override public void run (){
                for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                canalBC.receive();
                System.out.println("C");
                canalCB.send(1);
                }
          }
         } , "A");
         thCliente.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            canalCB.send(1);// Printing the first B
        procesoB(canalBC,canalCB);
        procesoC(canalBC,canalCB);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: That API is in spanish...

Answer (score 0):

Both processes try to receive first, then send, this leads to a deadlock.
Exchange the order of sending and receiving in one of the processes.